# Есть ли способ отображать юникод как симоволы кириллицы в редакторе Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode

У меня есть файлы properties, в которых юникодом закодированы сообщения, использующие кириллицу. Примерно так:

```
message=\u041E\u0442\u0441\u0441...
```

Я бы хотел вместо юникода прямо в редакторе видеть символы, которые они обозначают, вроде:

```
message=невозможно....
```

А также, иметь возможность непосредственной конвертации кириллицы в юникод прямо в редакторе.

Всё, что удалось найти, это плагин, который подсвечивает одиночный символ юникода, если навести на него курсор с нажатым ctrl. Однако, хотелось бы функционала побогаче.

[image: плагин unicode]

Comment: А может их там просто и написать?

Comment: Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings. Есть пункт на кодировку properties файлов.

Comment: @Tsyklop помогла установка флага Transpatern tative-to ascii conversion во включенное состояние, спасибо! Если оформите как ответ, помечу правильным.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Перейдите в настройки Идеи:

```
Settings -> Editor -> File Encodings
```

Там будут настройки кодировки для `properties` файлов. Выставите кодировку и включите опцию `Transparent native-to ascii conversion`.